# PrimeNG dialog component doesn't close when modal

Tags: angular, primeng

I've got a modal PrimeNG dialog component that looks like this

```
<p-dialog 
header="{{title}}" 
[(visible)]="display"
[modal]="true"
[dismissableMask]="true"
[closeOnEscape]="true"
[responsive]="true"
[closable]="false"
>
  {{content}}
</p-dialog>
```

The Issue I'm having is if the property `[closable]="false"` is set the dismissMask & escape properties stop working. As per [Docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) it says only the X should disappear.  How could I get rid the "X" with keeping the functionality of hideOnMask tap?

best regards, Aghi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make all of them true

```
<p-dialog 
header="{{title}}" 
[(visible)]="display"
[modal]="true"
[dismissableMask]="true"
[closeOnEscape]="true"
[responsive]="true"
[closable]="true"
>
  {{content}}
</p-dialog>
```

and change css of close button. you can see css classes from doc.

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display:none;
}
```